# Validator shows me some error

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, w3c-validation

I made an XML file and XML Schema for validation. I tried it but it gives me some error.

XML file is well-formed, XML Schema is well-formed, too. But when I try Validate XML with XSD it gives me some errors.
Pic: [LINK](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35284336/eror.JPG)

When I change line 2 in XSD to:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com">
```

It gives me another error Pic:[LINK](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35284336/error2.JPG)

Can you help me where I am making the mistake please?

---

Update from 2013-10-14 10:57 (copied from answer):

Sorry I am little bit overworked, I didn't realize that I have missing book tag. However, it still gives me an error.  What I am still doing wrong? I have attached my XML and XML schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com">
  <xs:element name="library">
   <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="book"/>
     <xs:element name="book_id" type="xs:integer"/>
     <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
     <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string"/>
     <xs:element name="count" type="xs:integer"/>
     <xs:element name="genre" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
 </xs:schema>



 <?xml version="1.0"?> 
  <library>
   <book>
    <book_id>5</book_id>
    <title>Sokak</title>
    <author>Tony</author>
    <count>6</count>
    <genre>epic</genre>
   </book>
   <book>
    <book_id>13</book_id>
   <title>Kucharka</title>
   <author>Fiona</author>
   <count>8</count>
   <genre>Hobby</genre>
  </book>
</library>
```

Comment: You don't have a book element in the xsd

Comment: Your schema doesn't accurately reflect the structure, I think.  A library contains a sequence of a complex type called book which contains elements like book ID and title.  That isn't what your schema says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tony Hopkinson has given you the answer, but hasn't marked it as an answer. You don't have a book element in the xsd.

Comment: Hardly worth answer. Perhaps we should have a tag called Doh! :)